# Can't seem to copy to network share in CMD

Tags: windows, backup, cmd.exe

I'm trying to write a simple script to back up specific files and directories, however it seems to fail when copying to the network drive. I've seen other similar issues advising to map the drive using net use, but on these systems `H:` will always be mounted already (I'm happy for the script to fail in instances when the drive hasn't been mounted). I've isolated it to the following line which also fails when pasting directly into CMD.

```
H:\>xcopy  "C:\Users\<user>\My Documents" "H:\<user>-backup-26022015\My Documents"  /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
Access denied
Unable to create directory - H:\<user>-backup-26022015\My Documents
File not found - *.*
0 File(s) copied
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One thing I don't like is seeing the "C:\Users\\".  There is an extra backslash there.  What happens if you use: "Dir H:".  What about "dir C: >> H:\Output.txt"  (Just tell us if those simple commands work or fail.)  Show us: "net use H:" on this machine, and "net share" on the machine sharing the directory, and especially "net share myCustomShareName" on the machine sharing the directory; that will show some permissions settings.  Of course, sanitize (replace any confidential details with custom examples) before posting anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you left your home directory out of the path on purpose, so make sure its in there.

Try this:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents" "H:\-backup-26022015\My Documents" /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
```

With win7 and later, your MyDocs directory is no longer actually called "My Documents", though explorer sometimes displays it that way, but that name is not really valid, so the command line requires the path as C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents. Even though the error message complains about creating the destination path, its real issue is the source path (I've confirmed this with testing).

Also note, you are nesting one My Docs dir inside another, by leaving a trailing slash off the source parameter, and specifying the folder name in the destination, so your files will end up in h:-backup-260215\My Documents\My Documents. if you want to fix that, add a trailing '\*' to the source path.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. I'm a bit confused by your other comment about the directory beginning with a hyphen. It doesn't, <username> is just a placeholder for the login name so the directory begins with letters.

Comment: I was referring to "H:\-backup". Thats how it appears to me. StackExchange sites usually eat any token with anglebraces, so perhaps you typed tokens that I'm not seeing. to me it appears that the backup folder name starts with '-'. That is legal and will wotk with many apps, but may be illegal for others. I don't believe its a legit name for FAT32 disks, but NTFS obiviously has no issue with it, since I tested your scenario with that destination name. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

As Frank said the error is because "My Documents" is a link (or at least Microsofts broken implementation there of) not a directory (as seen with `dir /a`). Also Check `icacls H:\` to be sure you have rights, also you might want to use [ISO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates (2015-02-25) so you can sort properly, or for backups you can use [tools more advanced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software) than xcopy. see wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link